# Why we often only see Webkit css tags that are for Apple's and Safari web browser? Should we use other rendering engine tags too?

Tags: html, css, browser, rendering

Since there are different rendering engines for different browsers, why we often only use Webkit CSS tags that are for Apple's and Safari web browser? Should we use other rendering engine tags too to make the web pages or emails look well across all major browsers? Such as Blink for Chrome, Gecko for FireFox, Presto for Opera?

Comment: I think it's better to make the opposite, abstract from browser differences, via the use of css known to work universally or by the use of some framework that hides those kind of tweaks from the programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A famous example of a best practise for multiple browsers:

```
#id_of_element {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Source: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/